# can't get vba to show code for all buttons

Tags: vba, ms-access

Working in VBA in Access

In one of my databases "General" in the drop down shows the code for all buttons.

For some reason this database does not, and I have to manually select each button... ie RunFDE, RunQP1

Not sure how to fix it.

Want to see code for all buttons at the same time.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.

Bottom left has Procedure View and Full Module View.

Full Module View is what I want.